# Show a group is a semi direct product

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, semidirect-product

Consider a set $G$ of $n \times n$ matrices with entries $\{0,1,-1\}$ that have exactly one non zero entry in each row a column. Show $G$ is a group and that $G$ is the semi direct product of the symmetric group $S_n$ and the group of diagonal matrices with entries in $\{1,-1\}$ (I'll call it $D$).

Well here's the first part:

Let $A,B,C \in G$.
Since matrix multiplication is associative it follows  $\forall A,B,C \in G$, $A(BC)=(AB)C$.

Since G is the set of $n \times n$ matrices with entries {0,+1,-1} that have exactly 1 non zero entry in each row a column, it follows $I \in G$. $IA=AI=A$ (where I is the identity matrix)

Since each row and column has exactly 1 non zero entry in each row, it follows $\forall A\in G$, $det(A) \neq0$. It follows $ \forall A\in G, \exists A^{-1}$ such that $ AA^{-1}=A^{-1}A=I$ Thus, every element in G is invertible.

Now for the second part: It makes sense that G is the semi direct product of $S_n$ and the group of diagonal matrices with entries in {+1,-1}. $S_n$ acts on D by just permuting is columns..but how can I show that G is the semi direct product?

Thanks!

p.s I see that there are 5 equivalent statements on wikipedia - If I can show just one is true then G is the semi direct product. How do I know which one to show? Is one better than another?

Comment: You can show that $G=S_nD$ and that $D$ is normal in $G$. Also, note that permuting columns is not an action of $S_n$ on $D$. The action should be the conjugate action in $G$.

Comment: Thanks Quang, can you tell me if im on the right track?: let A $\in$ G and let B $\in$ D. If D is normal if gD=Dg (left and right cosets are equal) also, D is a normal subgroup if $ABA^{-1}=B$

Comment: let A $\in$ G and let B $\in$ D. If D is normal if gD=Dg (left and right cosets are equal) also, D is a normal subgroup if $ABA^{-1}=B$ So I take the inverse of both sides (since they are invertible matrices) $AB^{-1)A^{-1}=B^{-1}$ which means $A(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}$ then multiplying by $A^{-1}$ I eventually get $(AB)^{-1}=(BA)^{-1} $so AB=BA. Since $AB \in gD$ and $BA \in Dg$ it follows that left and right cosets are equal, so D is normal is G?

Comment: No, $D$ is a normal subgroup if for any $B \in D$, and $A \in G$, that $ABA^{-1} \in D$. It is too restrictive to require that $A$ and $B$ commute, and in fact this is not necessarily the case (take $n= 2$ with $A = \begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$ and $B = \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}$ to see this).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I think is the easiest way:

Show $\phi: G \to S_n$ given by $\phi(A) = B$, where $A = (a_{ij})$ and $B = (b_{ij})$, and $b_{ij} = |a_{ij}|$, is a homomorphism (in other words, take the absolute value of every entry).

We then have that $\text{ker }\phi = D$, and $\phi|_{S_n} = 1_{S_n}$, and we are done.

(This exhibits a right-split of the short exact sequence $1 \to D \to G \to S_n \to 1$)